# get full type on prisma client

Tags: prisma

When i generate my prisma client with prisma generate, i got an index.d.ts with all types from my database.
But the probleme is that all type are "single" and there is no relations.
When i query something like

```
prisma.users.findMany({
            [... ]
            include: {
                cars: {
                  [...]
                }}});
```

prisma type the response dynamically with the right type

```
users & {
        cars: cars & {
           [...]
        };
    }
```

So everything work well and I have the auto completion, except if I want to pass this variable to another method, I would like to type the parameters, so I have to create my own type used as method parameter.

```
type prismaUsers = users & {
        cars?: cars & {
           [...]
        };
    }
```

But I'm asking if there is a way to get the "full" type from prisma to avoid me to create all "full" types with optionals sub-elements like I did for the user example. Or maybe i'm doing wrong and there is another way to do?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

An alternate method (my preferrence) to get the "full" type, or the model with all of its possible relations, is to use the `GetPayload` version of your model type. The type is a generic that can receive the same object you pass to your query.

```js
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

type UserWithCars = Prisma.UserGetPayload<{
  include: {
    cars: true;
  }
}>

const usersWithCars = await prisma.user.findMany({
  include: {
    cars: true,
  }
});
```

As your query grows more complex, you may want to abstract it and ensure that it is strongly typed.

```js
import { Prisma, PrismaClient } from "@prisma/client";

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const userInclude = Prisma.validator<Prisma.UserInclude>()({
  cars: true,
});

type UserWithCars = Prisma.UserGetPayload<{
  include: typeof userInclude;
}>;

const usersWithCars = await prisma.user.findMany({
  include: userInclude,
});
```

Comment: Upvoting because your solution does not need to create a function just to retrieve a type :) Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [Prisma Validator API](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/advanced-type-safety/prisma-validator) along with some typescript features to generate types for your query.

For the `findMany` example you mentioned

```js
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

// 1. Define a User type that includes the "cars" relation. 
const userWithCars = Prisma.validator<Prisma.UserArgs>()({
    include: { cars: true },
})

// 2: This type will include many users and all their cars
type UserWithCars = Prisma.UserGetPayload<typeof userWithCars>[]
```

If you simply want to automatically infer the return type of a prisma query wrapped in a function, you can use `PromiseReturnType`.

For example:

```js
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

async function getUsersWithCars() {
  const users = await prisma.user.findMany({ include: { cars: true } });
  return users;
}

type UsersWithCars = Prisma.PromiseReturnType<typeof getUsersWithCars>
```

You can read more about this in the [Operating against partial structures of your model types](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/advanced-type-safety/operating-against-partial-structures-of-model-types) concept guide in the Prisma docs.

Answer (score 9):

The best way is to use generic typing like this :

```
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

type UserWithMessages = Prisma.UserGetPayload<{
  include: {
    Message: {
      include: {
        MessageParam: true;
      };
    };
  };
}>;
```

Answer (score 9):

#### Full type of Model with all relations.

```js
type UserFullType = Prisma.UserGetPayload<{ select: { [K in keyof Required<Prisma.UserSelect>]: true } }>
```

#### You could also create maps for convenience.

```js
interface SelectMap {
  User: Prisma.UserSelect
  Post: Prisma.PostSelect
}

interface PayloadMap<S extends (string | number | symbol)> {
  User: Prisma.UserGetPayload<{ [K in S]: true }>
  Post: Prisma.PostGetPayload<{ [K in S]: true }>
}

type FullModel<M extends keyof SelectMap, S = Required<SelectMap[M]>> = PayloadMap<keyof S>[M]
```

#### Usage

```js
const user: FullModel<'User'>
```

---

## Update

Here is the workaround solution to make it using Model type as generic

```js
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T]
type PickByValue<T, V extends T[keyof T]> = { [ K in Exclude<keyof T, ValueOf<{ [ P in keyof T ]: T[P] extends V ? never : P }>> ]: T[K] }
type KeyOfValue<T, V extends T[keyof T]> = keyof PickByValue<T, V>
type PickValueByKey<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never

interface ModelMap {
  Article: Article
  User: User
}
interface SelectMap {
  Article: Prisma.ArticleSelect
  User: Prisma.UserSelect
}
interface PayloadMap<S extends (string | number | symbol)> {
  Article: Prisma.ArticleGetPayload<{ select: { [K in S]: true } }>
  User: Prisma.UserGetPayload<{ select: { [K in S]: true } }>
}
type FullModelType<M extends ValueOf<ModelMap>, N = KeyOfValue<ModelMap, M>, S = Required<PickValueByKey<SelectMap, N>>> = PickValueByKey<PayloadMap<keyof S>, N>
const article: FullModelType<Article> = {}
```

Answer (score 3):

The [above example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69943634/11044712) gives a really good solution, I just want to add how can you select specific attributes of a loaded entity.

In my example I have a todo entity and this entity has a author field on it. I want to load only name and id of the author entity

```js
import { type Todo, Prisma } from "@prisma/client";

const todoInclude = Prisma.validator<Prisma.TodoInclude>()({
  author: {
    select: {
      name: true,
      id: true,
    },
  },
});

type TodoWithUser = Prisma.TodoGetPayload<{
  include: typeof todoInclude;
}>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Most easily you can define the corresponding type with `typeof`:

```js
myQuery = await prisma.users.findMany({
            [... ]
            include: {
                cars: {
                  [...]
                }}});
type prismaUsers = typeof myQuery
```

Or if you decide to wrap your query inside a function, you may let TypeScript infer the return type for you:

```js
function queryUserWithCar(...) {
  return prisma.users.findMany({
            [... ]
            include: {
                cars: {
                  [...]
                }}});
}
```

and then extract the function's return type:

```js
type prismaUser = ReturnType<typeof queryUserWithCar> extends Promise<infer T> ? T : never
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify what I use this a year now since there was not a lot of answer yet:

I am still using my "own" type. I have a big file with all types where all properties are optional. It is not the best way because depending of the query, u have no access to all sub objects, but it is really pleasant to work with for the new devs.

It seem a bit heavy to develop but just need to add the new liaison when we change the database.

```
type prismaUser = users & {
        car?: prismaCar[];
        house?: prismaHouse;
    }

type prismaCar = car & {
        user?: prismaUser;
    }

type prismaHouse = house
```

On this example we only work with prismaUser, prismaCar and prismaHouse.

We think to change about new suggestions with generic type here when we gonna have time

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help,
I had this query

```
  await this.prisma.user.findMany({
    where: {
      patientData: {},
    },
    select: {
      id: true,
      firstName: true,
      lastName: true,
      email: true,
      patientData: {
        select: {
          credits: true,
        },
      },
      OrderHistory: {
        select: {
          name: true,
          date: true,
        },
      },
    },
  });
```

So I used RecursivePartial

```
export type RecursivePartial<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: RecursivePartial<T[P]>;
};
type UserWithPatientAndOrderHistory = RecursivePartial<
  Prisma.UserGetPayload<{
    include: {
      patientData: true;
      OrderHistory: true;
    };
  }>
>;
```