# Prisma + Nest JS, what Promise type should i use?

Tags: typescript, promise, prisma

What type should i use inside Promise (instead of ?) ? I dont know exactly what will return, because of second argument - UserSelect.

```
async getOneUser(where: Prisma.UserWhereUniqueInput, userSelect?: Prisma.UserSelect):Promise<?> {
  const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({ where, select: { ...userSelect } })
  return user
}
```

I want to be able to select specific fields to pass in the select statement, instead of passing all of them by default.

Comment: btw this has nothing to do with nestjs. It's just Prisma stuff. I'd drop that return type and see what typescript had inferred for me. (disclaimer: I didn't use Prisma before)

Comment: Maybe something like `Pick<User, UserSelect>`?

Answer (score 2):

I made type with all possible selects and then use it with Partial inside Promise. I think it is the best option:

```
export type UserFullType = Prisma.UserGetPayload<{ select: { [K in keyof Required<Prisma.UserSelect>]: true } }>


async getOneUser(
        where: Prisma.UserWhereUniqueInput,
        userSelect: Prisma.UserSelect = {}
    ): Promise<Partial<UserFullType>> {
        const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({ where, select: { ...userSelect } })
        return user
    }
```

[found useful info in this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68366105/get-full-type-on-prisma-client)

Answer (score 1):

you may use `any` or `Partial<T>`

```
// here I decide to use Partial<User> as return
async getOneUser(
  where: Prisma.UserWhereUniqueInput,
  userSelect: Prisma.UserSelect,
): Promise<Partial<User>> {
  const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({
    where,
    select: { ...userSelect },
  });
  return user as Partial<User>;
}
```

and we can call it as following

```
// here I use uuid
await this.userService.getOneUser(
  { id: '064c1764-1ab0-4936-a735-e764fbfaa84e' },
  { id: true, _count: true, name: true },
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in Versions prior 4.16.1, unfortunally it [seems to be broken](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/20422) since then:

```
public async getOneUser<T extends Prisma.UserSelect | undefined>(where: Prisma.UserWhereUniqueInput, userSelect: T): Promise<Prisma.UserGetPayload<{select: T}>> {
    const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({ where, select: { ...userSelect } });
    return user;
}
```